# Getting correct output in a shell script from the curl command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ip

I am getting my IP address using a curl command, and I want to save it as a shell variable.

I use the following command to get the ip address

```
curl ipinfo.io/ip
```

And I assign the variable thusly:

```
IPADDR=`curl ipinfo.io/ip`
```

but when I echo this, I get the following:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    14  100    14    0     0     41      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   164
24.18.247.198
```

All I want is 24.18.247.198. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
IPADDR=$(curl ipinfo.io/ip 2>/dev/null)
```

That is, the "% Total", "% Received" and others are printed on stderr. By redirecting stderr to `/dev/null` you can get rid of that noise.

Always use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` `` when possible.

Answer (score 3):

curl provides an attribute to operate "muted": -s

Hence, you can set your variable in this way:

```
IPADDR=$(curl -s ipinfo.io/ip)
```